# Python gRPC long pooling

Tags: python, long-polling, grpc

I have server which must nofity some clients across gRPC connection. 
Clients connect to server without timeout and wait for messages every time. Server will notify clients when new record was added to database.

How can I manage server for better performance with multithreading? May be should I use monitor and if record was added I would notify server side gRPC to retrieve data from database and send it to clients?
How do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have some better plans for later in time, but today the best solution might be [to implement something that presents the interface of `concurrent.futures.Executor` but that gives you better efficiency](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7632#issuecomment-239015940).